# How do I add to an existing object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding company name from a form to

```
$scope.master = {};
```

using

```
$scope.master = angular.copy(cmpy); 
// This gives me result as Object {cname: "Company 2"}
```

Now on another form, the owner details and I want to just add to `$scope.master`. I've tried `push`, `concat`, but they don't seem to work. If I use `copy` again, it just overwrites the existing data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AngularJS version >= 1.4.0 then you can use the `extend` feature like so:

```
angular.extend($scope.master, $scope.ownerDetails);
```

This will copy all the values from `$scope.ownerDetails` (or whatever place you are getting the owner details) to the `$scope.master`.

For Angular less than 1.4.0 you can workaround to inject your own `extend` method:

```
// This code is basically copied from AngualrJS 1.4.0 library
function baseExtend(dst, objs, deep) {
    var h = dst.$$hashKey;

    for (var i = 0, ii = objs.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        var obj = objs[i];
        if (!angular.isObject(obj) && !angular.isFunction(obj)) {
            continue;
        }

        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (var j = 0, jj = keys.length; j < jj; j++) {
            var key = keys[j];
            var src = obj[key];

            if (deep && angular.isObject(src)) {
                if (angular.isDate(src)) {
                    dst[key] = new Date(src.valueOf());
                } else {
                    if (!angular.isObject(dst[key])) {
                        dst[key] = angular.isArray(src) ? [] : {};
                    }
                    baseExtend(dst[key], [ src ], true);
                }
            } else {
                dst[key] = src;
            }
        }
    }
    if (h) {
        dst.$$hashKey = h;
    } else {
        delete dst.$$hashKey;
    }
    return dst;
}

angular.merge = function(dst) {
    var slice = [].slice;
    return baseExtend(dst, slice.call(arguments, 1), true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`push` and `concat` are for arrays and $scope.master is an object. To add another key:

```
$scope.master['owner_details'] = owner_details;
```

Comment: as i am using a format such as this - master.firstname, if i use $scope.master['owner_details'], it creates one extra level of key which is not required

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are fine to programmatically set the master variable if that's what you want (and you may well due to you trying push etc)

However if the "form" you mention is an *HTML form* of fields, you can just bind using *ngmodel* the user details into $*scope.master.* Like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="master.firstname" />
```

Just another option for you.

All the best.

Comment: This would have been fine, but the first form has one input field and when click on subit it calls a function which stores the value in master. The second form calls another function. If I use angular.copy again, it overwrites the value of the first form.